# Terrible flicker when using SKView in NSScrollView

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

Unfortunately using [SKView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013031) in a [NSScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/index.html) seems utterly unusable.

[Project available on github.](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/TerribleFlickerWithSKViewInNSScrollView/)

Does anybody have any clever workarounds or am I doing something very stupid?

- Terrible flicker when scrolling
- Terrible flicker when resizing the window
- The shape is a circle, however, the aspect ratio is getting all messed up.

I'm running this on a MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012), OS X 10.10.2; could be device specific.

[image: Terrible flicker]

Here is the code, everything is setup in AppDelegate,

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    @IBOutlet weak var spriteKitView: SKView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!

    var scene : SKScene?
    var rootNode : SKNode?
    var shape : SKShapeNode?
    var sprite : SKSpriteNode?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        let side = 500.0
        scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: side, height:side))
        scene?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
        spriteKitView.presentScene(scene)
        spriteKitView.setFrameSize(CGSize(width: side, height: side))
        scrollView.scrollPoint(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(side/2), y: CGFloat(side/2)))

        // Add root node
        rootNode = SKNode()
        scene!.addChild(rootNode!)

        // Add shape to root node
        shape = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(side/10))
        shape!.fillColor = NSColor.redColor()
        shape!.lineWidth = 1.0
        shape!.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(side/2), y: CGFloat(side/2))
        rootNode!.addChild(shape!)

        //
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image")
        rootNode!.addChild(sprite!)

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using NSScrollView, consider adding your content to a SKSpriteNode and use it as a 'worldNode' and adding all subsequent nodes as children. The worldNode can be of a much larger dimension than the actual view. Movement would then be accomplished by moving the worldNode.

Comment: That's a good idea. Any reason why to use a SKSpriteNode for this purpose? Would a SKNode work just as well?

Comment: No reason. Both would do the job.

Comment: I’ve tried the same thing, got much WORSE results. Not only did I have flashing but I also had the SKView magnify its contents just from changing the window dimensions—even though the SKView was set to be a constant width and height using NSView’s layout constraints.